# AWS Terraform: Filter specific subnets by matching substring in tag name

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have 6 subnets, I want to filter 3 subnets from them matching substring `internal` and use in rds.

Tag name has internal word and want to filter based on that.

Could anyone please help me?

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc_nonprod-sctransportationops-vpc" {
  tags {
    Name = "vpc_nonprod-sctransportationops-vpc"
  }
}
    
data "aws_subnet_ids" "all" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc_nonprod-sctransportationops-vpc.id}"
}
    
output "aws_subnet_ids" {
  value = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.all.ids}"
}
# 6 subnets
# Now look up details for each subnet
     

data "aws_subnet" "filtered_subnets" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_subnet_ids.all.ids)}"
  id    = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.all.ids[count.index]}"

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["*internal*"]
  }
}
```

Some tag name has `internal` substring

Need to grab all subnet id whose tag name has internal substring

`values = ["*"]` return `6` ids, however, `values = ["any word not work"]` or `values = ["*internal*"]` doesn't work.

Following are error:

```
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* data.aws_subnet.publicb: 3 error(s) occurred:

* data.aws_subnet.publicb[1]: data.aws_subnet.publicb.1: no matching subnet found
* data.aws_subnet.publicb[4]: data.aws_subnet.publicb.4: no matching subnet found
* data.aws_subnet.publicb[0]: data.aws_subnet.publicb.0: no matching subnet found
```

There should be 6 but I am getting only 3, that means there should be  partially good things and partially bad things.

These 3 subnets doesn't have `internal` substring in tag name.

It means it's parsing. `aws_subnet_ids` doesn't have filter option.

There should be instead. For one match, it will be simple, however, I need multiple matches.

In my guess now the error is because of loops which runs for 6 times.

Here is same output without filter:

```
"data.aws_subnet.filtered_subnets.2": {
    "type": "aws_subnet",
    "depends_on": [
        "data.aws_subnet_ids.all"
    ],
    "primary": {
        "id": "subnet-14058972",
        "attributes": {
            "assign_ipv6_address_on_creation": "false",
            "availability_zone": "us-west-2a",
            "cidr_block": "172.18.201.0/29",
            "default_for_az": "false",
            "id": "subnet-14038772",
            "map_public_ip_on_launch": "false",
            "state": "available",
            "tags.%": "4",
            "tags.Designation": "internal",
            "tags.Name": "subnet_nonprod-sctransportationops-vpc_internal_az2",
            "tags.Permissions": "f00000",
            "tags.PhysicalLocation": "us-west-2a",
            "vpc_id": "vpc-a47k07c2"
        },
        "meta": {},
        "tainted": false
    },
    "deposed": [],
    "provider": "provider.aws"
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`aws_subnet_ids` has this feature, however, different way. Here, it solved my problem:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "all" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc_nonprod-sctransportationops-vpc.id}"

  tags = {
    Name = "*internal*"
  }
}
```

Thanks for reviewing :D

Comment: `tags {` Blocks of type "tags" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument
"tags"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.

Comment: @Adan review: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html. ```data "aws_subnet_ids" "private" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Tier = "Private"
  }
}```

Comment: Yeah, the = in `tags = {` was missing.

Comment: Yeap that was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

According to the Terraform documentation `aws_subnet_ids` data source has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.67.0/docs/data-sources/subnet_ids).

You can use `aws_subnets` instead.

Example:

```
    # Private Subnets (db_subnet) 
    data "aws_subnets" "private_db_subnet" {

      filter {
        name   = "vpc-id"
        values = [data.aws_vpc.main_vpc.id]
      }

      tags = {
        Name = "{YOUR_FILTER}"
      }
    }
```

Its output is a list of subnets: `data.aws_subnets.private_db_subnet.ids`

Use case example:

```
    resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_json_documentdb" {
        ...
        vpc_config {
            subnet_ids             = data.aws_subnets.private_db_subnet.ids
            security_group_ids     = [aws_security_group.lambda_sg.id]
        }
        ...
    }
```