# How to get Subnet list from VPC with terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-batch

I've tried to get all subnet ids to add aws batch with terraform with following code:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "test_subnet_ids" {
  vpc_id = "default"
}
data "aws_subnet" "test_subnet" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_subnet_ids.test_subnet_ids.ids)}"
  id    = "${tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.test_subnet_ids.ids)[count.index]}"
}

output "subnet_cidr_blocks" {
  value = ["${data.aws_subnet.test_subnet.*.id}"]
}
```

Fortunately, it was working fine when I've tested like that. But when I tried to integrate with batch terraform like:

```
resource "aws_batch_compute_environment" "test-qr-processor" {
  compute_environment_name = "test-qr-processor-test"
  compute_resources {
    instance_role = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.test-ec2-role.arn}"
    instance_type = [
      "optimal"
    ]
    max_vcpus = 256
    min_vcpus = 0
    security_group_ids = [
      "${aws_security_group.test-processor-batch.id}"
    ]
    subnets = ["${data.aws_subnet.test_subnet.*.id}"]
    type = "EC2"
  }
  service_role = "${aws_iam_role.test-batch-service-role.arn}"
  type = "MANAGED"
  depends_on = [ "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.test-batch-service-role" ]
}
```

I've encountered following error message,

> Error: Incorrect attribute value type
>
> on terraform.tf line 142, in resource
>   "aws_batch_compute_environment" "test-processor":  142:     subnets =
>   ["${data.aws_subnet.test_subnet.*.id}"]
>
> Inappropriate value for attribute "subnets": element 0: string
>   required.

Please let me know why, thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`"${data.aws_subnet.test_subnet.*.id}"` is already `string array` type.

you should input value without `[ ]`

write code like :

```sh
subnets = "${data.aws_subnet.test_subnet.*.id}"
```

> See :
>
> Here's [A document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/batch_compute_environment.html) about `Resource: aws_batch_compute_environment`

Comment: How can I filter out public subnets and get only the private ones?

Comment: @Shell_Leko Hi, you can find it in [this repository's vpc.tf file](https://github.com/gnokoheat/ecs-with-codepipeline-example-by-terraform/blob/master/vpc.tf)

Comment: @GNOKOHEAT that file already starts with private and public subnets separated in the locals variable at the top. It doesn't answer Shell_Leko 's question

Comment: @Shell_Leko, This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48818168/11758843